# how to declare cursor in flask_mysqldb for only once

Tags: python, mysql, flask, mysql-python

I have this code(not complete)

```
@app.route('/', methods = ['GET','POST'])
def home():
    """
    the main function for routing home
    """
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            if not cursor:
                cursor = mysql.connection.cursor()
            url = request.form.get('link',"")
```

the thing is i have to re declare cursor every time inside request.method=='POST' block
if i declare it outside(say first line) i got an error saying cursor not defined.because the post connection is not active yet

Answer (score 1):

> In Flask, you can use the before_request decorator to create a cursor
> only once and reuse it in multiple routes. Here's an example: In this
> example, the cursor is created using mysql.connection in the
> before_request function, which runs before each request. The cursor is
> then stored in g (the Flask global request object), so it can be
> reused in multiple routes. The teardown_request function closes the
> cursor and the connection after each request.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'user'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = 'password'
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'database'

mysql = MySQL(app)

@app.before_request
def before_request():
    g.conn = mysql.connection
    g.cursor = g.conn.cursor()

@app.teardown_request
def teardown_request(exception):
    if hasattr(g, 'cursor'):
        g.cursor.close()
    if hasattr(g, 'conn'):
        g.conn.close()

@app.route('/')
def index():
    g.cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM table')
    data = g.cursor.fetchall()
    return data
```